# Change LoginView Role Groups template from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview, loginview

I have this loginview on my page. How do I switch the Role Group from code behind?

Say ... I am currently at a dad Login View Template , and I want to change to Admin Login View Template:

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
<RoleGroups>
 <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
    <ContentTemplate>
        I Am Admin    
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:RoleGroup>
<asp:RoleGroup Roles="GirlUser">
    <ContentTemplate>
        I Am A Girl
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:RoleGroup>
<asp:RoleGroup Roles="BoyUser">
    <ContentTemplate>
        I Am A Boy
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:RoleGroup>
 <asp:RoleGroup Roles="DadUser">
    <ContentTemplate>
        I Am A Dad
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:RoleGroup>
</RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: It will show the appropriate template based on the currently loged in user, if you want to show a different template then it needs to see you as a different user. If you want to show the content of the "DadUser" template when logged in as "Admin" user then you are using the wrong control.

Comment: This is a really useful article which you can refer to [Role-Based Authorization](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs)

Comment: I'm not using the build in asp.net membership login mechanism . what is your suggestion . i'm building an asp.net web application that using my own authentication system . i'm trying to create a web page that appear differently based on role , using multiple pages for each role is not a solution . what control do u think i should use . once logged in the role will be set at the session["Role"] .

Comment: Tq Izzy . Will go through that and see anything that i can pick.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="AdminView" runat="server">
        I Am Admin
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="GirlView" runat="server">
        I Am A Girl
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="BoyView" runat="server">
        I Am A Boy
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="DadView" runat="server">
        I Am A Dad
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</div>
</form>
```

I settle down with these. Changing view from Dad to admin code behind:

```
public void changeView(int index)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = index; 
}
```

where 0 = admin and 3 = dad .